# EF Core - Reference parent of parent with ForeignKey

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

I have the following data models:

Diagram:

```
public class Diagram
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("QuizId")]
        public Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
        public long QuizId { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public List<DiagramServer> Servers { get; set; }
        public List<DiagramServerEvent> AvaliableEvents { get; set; }
    }
```

DiagramServer: (Child of Diagram)

```
public class DiagramServer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DiagramId")]
    public Diagram Diagram { get; set; }
    public long DiagramId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<DiagramServerEvent> Events { get; set; }
}
```

DiagramServerEvent: (Child of both Diagram and DiagramServer)

```
public class DiagramServerEvent
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Payload { get; set; }
    public float XCoordinate { get; set; } 
    public long EventId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DiagramId")]
    public Diagram Diagram { get; set; }
    public long? DiagramId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DiagramServerId")]
    public DiagramServer Server { get; set; }
    public long? DiagramServerId { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have `DiagramId` in the DiagramServerEvent reference the root diagram. This seems to be an issue because some of the events are children of the `DiagramSever` which then is a child of `Diagram`. Is there a way to manually configure this? Or is this a bad model in the first place?

I'm also using the Pomelo connector for EF Core to support MySQL.

Here is an overview of the  [DiagramServerEvent entries in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfCfj.png). The first three entries are children of the Diagram object, the rest are children of various DiagramServer objects. The `[ForeignKey("DiagramId")` reference from DiagramServerEvent does not seem to work when Diagram is not the closest parent.

Comment: Where's the error? What's happening? Please provide more information

Comment: Before I made 'DiagramId' in DiagramServerEvent nullable, a Foreign key constraint error was thrown, once I made it nullable, it defaults no null. It seems to fails to reference any object that is not it's direct parent. I read something about EF core not having recursive capabilities, maybe that's the cause?

Comment: Ok so the problem is resolved ?

Comment: No it's not, it's still not referencing the Diagram. If you look at the image of the table I linked, ALL entries in that table should have a reference to a Diagram, currently only the top 3 entries do. (Those top 3 entries was submitted as 'AvaliableEvents', direct children og the Diagram object)